# Writing variables and strings to a text file (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, file

I was surfing on the Net a lot, but still I haven't found an answer to my question: how to write variables to a .txt file and what's the best way to write NSStrings to .txt files. I've tried using **writeToFile** method, but if I have two calls of this method, then the text that was written when the first one was called will be overwritten. I want to have a kind of history of what has happened, and values of some variables in my .txt file. How should I do it?

Comment: Pull the text out of your file, append the string you have to the text, and write it again.

Comment: @Dustin If you're saving a lot of text (say a data stream or something), you end up reading back a whole file into memory just to add a few characters at the end. I think it's better to append using the OutPutStream from Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to append a string to a .txt file, you could do this:

```
NSString *string = ...;   // your string
NSString *path = ...;     // path to your .txt file
// Open output file in append mode:
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:path append:YES];
[stream open];
// Make NSData object from string:
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// Write data to output file:
[stream write:data.bytes maxLength:data.length]; // XXX 
[stream close];
```

*Remark:* If this is in an .mm file and therefore compiled as Objective-C++, then the second to last line (marked with XXX) must be replaced by

```
[stream write:static_cast<const uint8_t *>(data.bytes) maxLength:data.length];
```

because C++ requires an explicit cast from `const void *` to `const uint8_t *`.