# Write to file without overwriting ObjC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to write text to a file, but when searching for solution, I find "read-append-write" everywhere, but the file is too large for the memory of an iOS device, and it freezes, and resprings.
Is there any other solution to do it?

Comment: For appending text to a file, you might find this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989046/writing-variables-and-strings-to-a-text-file-objective-c/11990021#11990021 useful.

Comment: Do you want to write to the end of file without reading it? NSFileHandle can help

Comment: @voromax I just added an answer for that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `NSFileHandle` class in order not to have to read the whole file into memory (which is, by the way, bad practice for any file!):

```
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/path/to/file.ext"];
[fh seekToEndOfFile];

NSData *data = // obtain an NSData somehow
[fh writeData:data];
[fh closeFile];
```

Comment: @voromax thanks! :) (unfortunately I hit the rep cap for today, but anyway... ;)

Comment: Köszi ;) This helped me a lot.